# Magento:System Configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, system-configuration

This is my system.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <Threede_extensions translate="label" module="designit">
            <label>Threede Extensions</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </Threede_extensions>
    </tabs>  
    <sections>
        <designit>
            <label>Design It Settings</label>
            <tab>Threede_extensions</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> 
           <groups>
               <general translate="label" module="designit">
                   <label>General</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enablemodule translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Module</label>                            
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>90</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enablemodule>
                        <keytoken translate="label" module="designit">
                            <label>Token</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </keytoken>
                        <validate translate="label" module="designit">
                            <comment>Please save configuration value before validating.</comment>
                            <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                            <frontend_model>designit/adminhtml_system_config_form_field_validate</frontend_model>
                            <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </validate>
                    </fields>
                </general>
                <synchronize translate="label" module="designit">
                   <label>Synchronize Products</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <import translate="label">
                            <label>Products</label>
                            <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                            <frontend_model>designit/adminhtml_system_config_form_field_productimport</frontend_model>
                            <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </import>
                   </fields>
                </synchronize>
           </groups>                            
        </designit>
    </sections>
</config>
```

This is my validate.php file

```
<?php

    class Threede_Designit_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Field_Validate extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field 
    {
        /*
         * Set template
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->setTemplate('designit/system/config/form/field/validate.phtml');
        }

        /**
         * Return element html
         *
         * @param  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
         * @return string
         */
        protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
        {
            return $this->_toHtml();
        }

        /**
         * Return ajax url for button
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getAjaxCheckUrl()
        {
            return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/designit/validate');
        }

        /**
         * Generate button html
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getButtonHtml()
        {
            $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                'id'        => 'token_button',
                'label'     => $this->helper('adminhtml')->__('Validate Token'),
                'onclick'   => 'javascript:validate(); return false;'
            ));

            return $button->toHtml();
        }
    }
```

This is Productimport.php

```
<?php

class Threede_Designit_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Field_Productimport extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field 
{
    /*
     * Set template
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('designit/system/config/form/field/productimport.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Return element html
     *
     * @param  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Return ajax url for button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductImportUrl()
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/designit/import');
    }

    /**
     * Generate button html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
            'id'        => 'productimport_button',
            'label'     => $this->helper('adminhtml')->__('Synchronize Product'),
            'onclick'   => 'javascript:validate(); return false;'
        ));

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
```

This is productimport.phtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function validate() {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getProductImportUrl() ?>', {
            method:     'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport){
                data = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                alert(data.status_message)
            }
        });
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<?php echo $this->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

This is validate.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function validate() {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getAjaxCheckUrl() ?>', {
            method:     'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport){
                data = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                alert(data.status_message)
            }
        });
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<?php echo $this->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

This is controller

```
<?php

class Threede_Designit_Adminhtml_DesignitController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('designit/items')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
    }
    public function validateAction()
    {

        $data['token'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('designit/general/keytoken');
        $model = Mage::getModel('designit/designit');
        $result = $model->callApi($data,'validate-token');
        //$result = $model->callApi($data,'stores/products');
        //Mage::log($result,null,'test.log');exit;
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($result);
    }  

    public function importAction()
    {

        $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                ->setType('catalog_product')
                ->getTypeId();
        $attributeSetName   = 'Threede Set';
        $attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                            ->getFirstItem()
                            ->getAttributeSetId();

        $data['token'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('designit/general/keytoken');
        $model = Mage::getModel('designit/designit');
        $result = $model->callApi($data,'stores/products');
        $decoderesult = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($result);

        foreach ($decoderesult['products'] as $key=>$pdct) {
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            $image_url  = $pdct['image']; 
            //Mage::log($image_url,null,'12.log');
            $imageString = file_get_contents($pdct['image']);
            $save = file_put_contents('/var/www/html/mage1/media/threede',$imageString);

            //~ $imageString = file_get_contents($image_url);
            //~ $save = file_put_contents('Image/saveto/image.jpg',$imageString);
            Mage::log($imageString,null,'1235.log');
            Mage::log($save,null,'1246.log');
            $product

            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
            ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
            ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time

            ->setSku($pdct['product_id']) //SKU
            ->setName('New') //product name
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
            ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            ->setThreedeeProductType($pdct['type'])
            ->setThreedeeProductId($pdct['id'])
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility

            ->setPrice($pdct['price']) //price in form 11.22
            ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22

            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')

            ->setDescription($pdct['description'])
            ->setShortDescription($pdct['description'])

            //~ ->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
            //~ ->addImageToMediaGallery(.$image_url, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery

            ->setStockData(array(
                               //'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                               'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                               //'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                              // 'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                               'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                               'qty' => 999 //qty
                           )
            )

            ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
            $product->save();
        }
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($result);
    }   

}
```

This is sytem config section http://i.prntscr.com/bb36c5a33c794902beb838db4ce5e308.png

But when I click on both button,same controller action is calling.
http://i.prntscr.com/767754f12fef4b2b9d4cdffd7559f087.png

Please help. Both are working individually on commenting one section group  code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Javascript function name conflict issue, 
update your **Productimport.php**

```
public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
            'id'        => 'productimport_button',
            'label'     => $this->helper('adminhtml')->__('Synchronize Product'),
            'onclick'   => 'javascript:syncProducts(); return false;'
        ));

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
```

and update your  **productimport.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function syncProducts() {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getProductImportUrl() ?>', {
            method:     'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport){
                data = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                alert(data.status_message)
            }
        });
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<?php echo $this->getButtonHtml() ?>
```